# NetBeans can't build any type of Cordova project. Path already exists error

Tags: netbeans, cordova

I've just gotten a new iMac (OSX Mavericks) and installed the latest NetBeans 7.4 + Cordova + NodeJS + PhoneGap and verified that all installations went well and CLI commands are working properly.

I also installed and setup the Android SDK and emulator and that works fine too and I setup the SDK path in Netbeans too. Git is also installed fresh.

However, in NetBeans, when I start a new Cordova project with the built-in Cordova template (or ANY Cordova project for that matter) and try to deploy it on any Cordova emulator (Android, iOS, etc.), I keep getting the same error below:

```
cordova -d . create com.mego.TestCordova TestCordova 
Error: Path already exists and is not empty: /Users/wzeenni/Development/Projects/Prototypes/TestCordova 
Creating a new cordova project with name "TestCordova" and id "com.coolappz.TestCordova" at location "/Users/wzeenni/Development/Projects/Prototypes/TestCordova" 
    at CLI.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/create.js:63:25) 
    at new CLI (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:105:30) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:41:16) 
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26) 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) 
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32) 
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) 
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10) 
    at startup (node.js:119:16) 
    at node.js:901:3 
/Users/wzeenni/Development/Projects/Prototypes/TestCordova/nbproject/build.xml:78: exec returned: 1 
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

This also happens when I right-click the project > Properties > Cordova > Create Cordova Resorces button. It just shows me a loading screen then gives the same error output above and I don't get the chance to edit any values.

This is really frustrating as I did not change any settings on my default NetBeans install and tried different ways to get it to work, but to no avail.

I even tried this on my Linux Mint box, but I get the same error message. I know what "Path Already Exists" means, but I'm not really given a choice in NetBeans to change anything.

Any ideas? Is there something I need to install that I missed? Note I have not tried this on Windows yet. Just OSX Mavericks and Linux Mint.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: i have this error too , but after upgrade from 8.0.1 to 8.0.2  problem solved

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm guessing you have Cordova 3.1.0-0.2.0? (run cordova -v in command line to find out). It seems like they changed something in the "0.2.0" update and this is not compatible with NetBeans. Workaround is to uninstall this version and install older version of Cordova instead:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g cordova
sudo npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.1.0
```

And then it will work. I reported it against NetBeans, see [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=237918)

Comment: Ladar, thanks for that. Worked like a charm. I guess I'll wait till someone at the NetBeans team patches things up to use the latest Cordova, but this is great for now. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1940569 Since it worked for you, won't you at least mark the answer as 'Accepted'? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can 'patch' cordova Cordova 3.1.0-0.2.0 commenting lines 61 to 64 on create.js cordova file or downgrade to 3.1.0-0.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded and installed NetBeans 7.4 for Windows, but it seems a post-installation update is required (run "Check for Updates" in NetBeans) to pull in the fix for this issue, as [described here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=237918).

Answer (score 0):

There's an update for the cordova plugin, just update your plugin and you are good to go. It worked for me in NetBeans 8.0.1