# Netbeans cannot create build/create cordova application

Tags: netbeans, cordova

I try to create a sample Cordova project in Netbeans after starting an Android emulator.

This is exactly what I am getting when I run the project:

```
cordova.cmd -d create C:\DOCUME~1\user\LOCALS~1\Temp\/nb_temp_project com.coolappz.Cordova Cordova
Creating a new cordova project with name "Cordova" and id "com.coolappz.Cordova" at location "C:\DOCUME~1\user\LOCALS~1\Temp\nb_temp_project"
Using stock cordova hello-world application.
cordova library for "www" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Copying stock Cordova www assets into "C:\DOCUME~1\user\LOCALS~1\Temp\nb_temp_project\www"
Copying 6 files to C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\netbeans7.41projects\Cordova
Deleting directory C:\DOCUME~1\user\LOCALS~1\Temp\nb_temp_project
Deleting directory C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\netbeans7.41projects\Cordova\www
Copying 13 files to C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\netbeans7.41projects\Cordova\www
create-android:
cordova.cmd -d platform add android
cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
'C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
Creating android project...
Running command: cmd args=["/c","C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\.cordova\\lib\\android\\cordova\\3.4.0\\bin\\create","--cli","C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\My Documents\\netbeans7.41projects\\Cordova\\platforms\\android","com.coolappz.Cordova","Cordova"]
Command finished with error code 1: cmd /c,C:\Documents and Settings\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create,--cli,C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\netbeans7.41projects\Cordova\platforms\android,com.coolappz.Cordova,Cordova
operable program or batch file.
C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\netbeans7.41projects\Cordova\nbproject\build.xml:145: exec returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NetBeans can't build any type of Cordova project. Path already exists error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752701/netbeans-cant-build-any-type-of-cordova-project-path-already-exists-error)

Answer (score 0):

First, try to run your project in web browser before you build in Android application. If there is no error or bug, then compile the project to Apk. you have to connect internet while in progress